# How do I make a stop watch batch script

Tags: loops, batch-file, timer, stopwatch

I want to make a very simple "stop watch" like script that will start a timer when I kit a key. I just want to be able to track exactly how long small tasks are taking then add up them when I'm finished. I'm thinking a script that would start a timer then stop it when I hit a key, display that time then begin a new timer, and so on...  It would have to keep all the times, perhaps line by line and keep going on until I stop it.

Any ideas?

Comment: *any ideas??* yep, plenty of ideas. Any attempt from your part?

Comment: At the time I had no idea how to even begin writing this but no longer need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See here:
[How do I add a timer to a batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10559387/how-do-i-add-a-timer-to-a-batch-file)

Here:
[How do I create a batch file timer to execute / call another batch throughout the day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299392/how-do-i-create-a-batch-file-timer-to-execute-call-another-batch-throughout-th)

And here:
http://www.computerhope.com/forum/index.php?topic=140384.0